# How to split a statement based on dots ('.'), while excluding dots inside angular brackets(< . >) using regular expressions in python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to split statements by dots using regex in python, while excluding certain dots inside the angular brackets.
eg:
Original Statement :

```
'my name 54. is <not23.> worth mentioning. ok?'
```

I want to split it into following sentences:

```
Statement 1 : 'my name 54'
Statement 2 : ' is <not23.> worth mentioning'
Statement 3 : ' ok'
```

I have attempted

```
re.split(r'[^<.>]\.','my name 54. is <not23.> worth mentioning. ok?')
```

But, it's not ignoring dot inside <>, 
so the result am getting is:

```
['my name 5', ' is <not23', '> worth mentioning', ' ok?']
```

Comment: Where's your regex, and what's the problem with it?

Comment: It's in the description.

Comment: No, that's the task you're trying to complete. Where is **your attempt to complete it**?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give a [mcve].

Comment: Here goes the attempt @jonrsharpe : 
re.split(r'[^<.>]\.','my name 54. is <not23.> worth mentioning. ok?')
But, it's not ignoring dot inside<>, so the result am getting is:
['my name 5', ' is <not2', '> worth mentionin', ' ok?']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on the following regex:

```
\.(?![^<]*>)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/uL1uI5/1)

```
import re

str = 'my name 54. is <not23.> worth mentioning. ok?'
regex = re.compile(r"\.(?![^<]*>)")
arr = regex.split(str)

print(arr)
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks. It works. So, can we say that the pattern expression followed by ?! in a regex would be ignored from the expression in question?

Comment: `(?!...)` constructs a negative lookahead which asserts that current position (preceeded by a literal `.`) is not going to be followed by a `>` @AdityaKuls

Answer (score 1):

Easy if you can user the newer [**`regex` module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) (it provides the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` functionality):

```
import regex as re

string = 'my name 54. is <not23.> worth mentioning. ok?'
rx = re.compile(r"<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\.")

parts = rx.split(string)
print(parts)
# ['my name 54', ' is <not23.> worth mentioning', ' ok?']
```

Comment: How to install and use the newer regex module. I am getting the following error while using your suggestion:  "sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat"

Comment: `pip install regex` should be fine.